# converse js reconnects on every page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using converse js with xmpp server. I was having an issue that whenever the page is refreshed the chat box was disconnected and reconnecting again. I made the following code to fix it and it works good on fire fox but in google chrome it does not connect and keep showing as connecting..

This is an original code that reconnects chat on every page reload:

```
$(window).load(function(){

$("#jidy").val('<?php echo osc_logged_user_id();  ?>@xmpp');
$("#pass").val('<?php echo osc_logged_user_id(); ?>');
$(".login-submit").trigger("click");
$("#controlbox").hide();

});
```

This is modified code below that works good on firefox but not on google chrome:

```
$(document).ready(function(){     
 require(['converse'], function (converse) {
 converse.initialize({
 });
});

$("#jidy").val('<?php echo osc_logged_user_id();  ?>@xmpp');
$("#pass").val('<?php echo osc_logged_user_id(); ?>');
$(".login-submit").trigger("click");
$("#controlbox").remove();
$('.conn-feedback').remove();
$("#toggle-controlbox").remove();



});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var xmppSubmit = setInterval(function()
 {
     if(jQuery(".login-submit").length > 0)
     {
         if(readCookie("xmpp_username") != null && readCookie("xmpp_password") != null)
         {
             jQuery('input[id="xmpp_username"]').val(readCookie("xmpp_username"));
             jQuery('input[id="xmpp_password"]').val(b64_to_utf8(readCookie("xmpp_password")));
             jQuery('input[class="login-submit"]').trigger('click');
         }
         clearInterval(xmppSubmit);
     }
 }, 700);

function utf8_to_b64( str ) {
  return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent( str )));
}

function b64_to_utf8( str ) {
  return decodeURIComponent(escape(window.atob( str )));
}
```

because `dom` might not loaded.